# elasticdump error while performs export or import

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-opendistro

whenever i start to import or export the data, i faced this error from elasticdump...

`starting dump
Mon, 07 Oct 2019 06:15:25 GMT | got 5 objects from source file (offset: 0)
Mon, 07 Oct 2019 06:15:26 GMT | Error Emitted => Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
Mon, 07 Oct 2019 06:15:26 GMT | Total Writes: 0
Mon, 07 Oct 2019 06:15:26 GMT | dump ended with error (set phase)  => TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined`

any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Which version of Elasticdump and ES are you using?

Comment: Hi @Val am currently use elasticdump 2.2.0 and elasticsearch 1.2.0

Comment: Elasticsearch 1.2.0 is a very, very, very old version. You can either use elasticdump 2.1.0 or upgrade Elasticsearch to at least 2.x

Comment: Hi @Val , as per this website https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/version-history/  i think 1.2.0 is already updated isnt it ?

Comment: Ok Open Distro 1.2.0 means Elasticsearch 7.2.0, so a very recent version. In this case, you need to upgrade elasticdump to the most recent version, 2.2.0 is too old and not compatible.

Comment: do u have any idea on how to get the updated elasticdump ? because every npm i did it will pull this version